# Best way to manage a list of url, text and image

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

In a theme I'm developing I need to manage a list of title, url and image. It's very similar to a menu item but there is an additional information that is associated with every item that is an image. Which is the best way to manage that on wordpress admin console and retrieve it via code?
I find some plugin that allows to have a widget with text and image but it's not satisfying.

Any idea?

Comment: register a post type with specific metabox for each item that you need,

Comment: I need to create 2 menus in which each item as an image associated do you think that is the best way? Is there anyway to add image property to a menu_item?

Comment: These http://i.imgur.com/BOkoO2g.png are all the data you can add on each menu item, I'm not sure how you're going to use the data but you can use Description and Title attribute for additional information where you can retrieve later, e.g. you can place Image URL on description

Comment: Yes these field can be used but since the admin are not so technical I was looking for a solution in which the user can add an image and not put an URL that has to be copied from the media section

Comment: You either use Menu Post type or create your own post type